# Strange behaviour with Transitions

Tags: java-me, transition, lwuit, lwuit-form

I set `transitions` to a Form :

```
public class Ecran extends Form {

    private Transition transIn = CommonTransitions.createSlide(CommonTransitions.SLIDE_VERTICAL, true, 250);
    private Transition transOut = CommonTransitions.createSlide(CommonTransitions.SLIDE_VERTICAL, false, 250);

    public Ecran()
    {
        super();
        setTransitionInAnimator(transIn);
        setTransitionOutAnimator(transOut);
    }

    public Ecran(String titre)
    {
        super(titre);
        setTransitionInAnimator(transIn);
        setTransitionOutAnimator(transOut);
    }
}

public class MenuPrincipalForm extends Ecran implements ActionListener, FocusListener, Runnable 
{
   ...
}
```

The problem is that in runtime the `transition` slides **twice** ! So how to make it slide only once ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use only the out transition for forms. Transition in allows more elaborate cases for forms and is useful for cases such as dialogs.